# Проблемы с git push и git commit

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

При коммите сообщение ошибка:

```
fatal: paths 'finish email ...' with -a does not make sense
```

Если ввожу git push

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Зайдя на гитхаб изменений не вижу
До этого помогал человек с кодом, он мой гит запуллил, я его изменения сохранила, проект полностью работает, только git не пушит

Comment: похоже Вы пытаетесь сделать коммит (git commit)  с параметром -a, что бы добавить все файлы. Но что то пошло не так. Покажите полную команду коммита. А так как ничего не закоммитилось, то и пушить нечего и изменений на гитхабе нет

Comment: Вангую что надо добавить кавычки вокруг текста сообщения

Comment: И в общем вам надо либо научится работать с командной строкой, либо найти подходящий инструмент для работы с git-ом мышкой

Comment: Объясняю, как ваш вопрос выглядит для других: "я ввожу (*какую-то, вам не скажу*) команду, и у меня ошибка. Помогите". Это как в кабинете врача сказать "у меня болит, вылечите", но не сказать, что и как болит.

Answer (score 1):

> fatal: paths 'finish email ...' with -a does not make sense

Перевожу почти дословно: Указывать пути/файлы 'finish email ...' одновременно с параметром -a — бессмысленно!

Что делать:

Указать или конкретные файлы для коммита или параметр `-a`, но не одновременно.